# Explorer.exe keep writes registry entry silently upon right click on certain file types

Tags: registry, explorer, windows-11, open-with

Note: file types that i see the problem: .jpg, .mp4

When right-clicking on file type above, context menu appear (windows 11 new context menu) and Process Monitor program detects 2 registry queries by Explorer.exe which is checking and set registry value. but, for old windows 10 context menu, it happens when "Open with.." sub context menu appear

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI948.png)

it adds:

`HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache\C:\Users\M..FriendlyAppName`

seems like it keeps trying to add the non-existent program to those file type into registry even i delete them million times.

on windows 11 new context menu, it appears as "M." on Open With list programs

on windows 10 old context menu, no "M." appear at list in "open with" sub context menu but the value still in registry.

anybody can help me?

i already scan my drives for virus but no virus found.

i already do sfc scan.

i think something wrong with my explorer.exe.